# how to update a gridview with photos inside a fragment

Tags: java, android, image, android-fragments, gridview

I'm trying to update a grid view using a custom adapter inside a fragment, but it just doesn't work. The idea is that upon clicking a button, a picture of a tree should be put inside the gridview

```
private void addPicture(View view){
       gridView=view.findViewById(R.id.imageSlot);
       galleryArrayList.add(new PictureClass(R.drawable.tree));
       adaptor=new ImageAdaptor(requireContext(),galleryArrayList);
       gridView.setAdapter(adaptor);

   }
```

this is the function that adds the picture to the gridview

```
               public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

                   View listItemView = convertView;
                   if (listItemView == null) {
                       // Layout Inflater inflates each item to be displayed in GridView.
                       listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
                   }

                   PictureClass pictureClass = getItem(position);

                   ImageView courseIV = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.imageSlot);


                   courseIV.setImageResource(pictureClass.getImageID());
                   return listItemView;
               }
           }
```

this is the adapter code

I was expecting it to just insert the tree photo in to the grid upon clicking a button, but instead it is collapsed. Is there a way to make it work, ideally without having to remake the adaptor?